# Can I train oscilloscope waveform by Yolov8?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

I only have little amount of dataset(200 total), and all of them are from Oscilloscope waveform. I use yolov8 for object detection, but it seem not really good as COCO dataset

Here's something I'd try:

1.Image Augmentation(Using roboflow)

2.Resize

3.Tuning hyperparameter

but it still worse than I thought. It barely predict any of label

I am curious about yolov8 can detect line or edge?
Or should I modify yolov8 or change to other object detection model for small object?

Thanks